# How can I remove duplicate relationships in a MySQL table data?

Tags: sql

I have a table "friends" with "user1" and "user2" columns.

How can I remove duplicate relationships?
For example, if I already have
`user1=1` and `user2=3`, 
how can I remove `user1=3` and `user2=1` values?

Could I enforce that in MySQL with a unique index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query you can find duplicate relationships

```
SELECT * 
FROM friends d
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM friends f
WHERE f.user1 = d.user2
AND f.user2 = d.user1
AND f.user2 < f.user1
)
```

**I recommend put the lower userId for user1 and create a unique index**

Answer (score 1):

For example, don't allow rows, where `user1` > `user2`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the other columns in your table you could create a composite primary key over the 2 columns to enforce the uniqueness.

Answer (score -1):

To find the duplicates, just join the table to itself. It is not difficult.